# MediaManager take too longer time for buffering mp3 file from url in android

Tags: android, xamarin, android-mediaplayer

I am creating a audio player using MediaManager. It working fine, but I noticed that its taking about 25 seconds to start the player then audio plays.

My internet connection is very fast.

When I play this audio in browser via url then its starts very quickly, whereas my android is not the same.

So what is the actual reason for taking this time to start play in android?

Comment: Hi , you can share the code ,  that will be helpful to check where problem is .

Comment: MediaManager works fine with properly encoded .mp3 files. Check if the files were encoded with the Fraunhofer encoder.